# How to merge two ElasticSearch documents for Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I have the following 'jobs' table in ElasticSearch with three columns: TIME, JOB_NAME and JOB_STATUS (START or END).
Every time a job STARTs or ENDs, it is sent to ElasticSearch as a separate document (via Logstash)

I'd like to search in Kibana for all jobs that started and have not yet ended.

How can I group by JOB_NAME, and only show those that have "impair" counts ? (TWO STARTS & ONE END for example) or ideally, show all the jobs that have more STARTS than ENDS

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using Logstash, I would use an [enrichment lookup](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/lookup-enrichment.html#es-def) and update start events with an end. This will make your visualizations a lot easier later on — just get all the events without an end.

Otherwise you might be able to do this at query time with a [bucket selector aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html) for unbalanced buckets, but I'm not sure this is going to be helpful with Kibana visualizations.